# Leaflet JavaScript bearings do not match Python calculations

Tags: javascript, python, geometry, geojson, geodesic-sphere

In my app, I use bearing for detection of signal intersection.
I use the following python code for detecting intersection of bearings:

```py
import nvector as nv

def bearing_intersect_nvector(point_0, bearing_0, point_1, bearing_1):
    point_a1 = nv.GeoPoint(point_0[0], point_0[1], degrees=True)
    point_a2 = point_a1.displace(10, bearing_0, degrees=True)[0]
    point_b1 = nv.GeoPoint(point_1[0], point_1[1], degrees=True)
    point_b2 = point_b1.displace(10, bearing_1, degrees=True)[0]
    path_a = nv.GeoPath(point_a1, point_a2)

    path_b = nv.GeoPath(point_b1, point_b2)
    point_c = path_a.intersect(path_b)
    point_c = point_c.to_geo_point()
    lat, lon = point_c.latitude_deg, point_c.longitude_deg
    return Coord(lon, lat)
```

On JavaScript I use the following code for second point of line for drawing bearing line:

```js
  const end_x = (startCoords as LatLng).lng + length * Math.cos(-(angle - 90) * Math.PI / 180);
  const end_y = (startCoords as LatLng).lat + length * Math.sin(-(angle - 90) * Math.PI / 180);
```

But the issue is that bearing drawn with JavaScript code using `end_x` and `end_y` as end coordinates do not match with bearing drawn calculated point of intersection using python code above.

The same issue I have with the following python code, it matches above JavaScript bearing calculation, but the bearing do not match with nvector calculation.

```py
import math
from geojson import LineString, Feature, Point
from turfpy.misc import line_intersect

def bearing_intersect_turfpy(point_0, bearing_0, point_1, bearing_1):
    def add_bearing(coord, angle):
        length = 1
        end_lat = coord["coordinates"][0] + length * math.sin(-(angle - 90) * math.pi / 180)
        end_lon = coord["coordinates"][1] + length * math.cos(-(angle - 90) * math.pi / 180)
        azimuth = Feature(geometry=LineString([coord, Point((end_lat, end_lon))]))
        return azimuth

    point_0 = Point((point_0[0], point_0[1]))
    point_1 = Point((point_1[0], point_1[1]))
    bearing_0 = add_bearing(point_0, bearing_0)
    bearing_1 = add_bearing(point_1, bearing_1)
    point_2 = line_intersect(bearing_0, bearing_1)["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"]
    return Coord(point_2[1], point_2[0])
```

I wondering why ?? And which calculation is proper ??
From my experience nvector implementation works much better, than simple geometry calculated, but I am not sure why ...